# How to fix a white screen of death?

Tags: theming, database

I am dealing with a white screen of death I feel like I've pin pointed the issue, but have no way of knowing how to fix it.

This is my first time using Drupal, and my first time running into this issue. Are these errors that are in my log, related to problem? How would I go about fixing it?

[image]

Any and all help is appreciated as I have already consulted the handbook and have not found the solution to this issue by doing so.

Comment: Seems like you might have drag the apache config into the Drupal folder or viceversa

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! It's an error from an Apache module; it's nothing Drupal can control or change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your **php.ini** (in most cases found in /etc/php5/apache2/) and modify the following options:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Reload or restart apache after saving.

If you don't have access to this file, you can also put this in your settings file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, set **Logging and errors** to **All** in the Drupal settings (admin/config/development/logging).

Answer (score 1):

running `drush core-requirements`from your drupal site's directory [more info](http://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/core/core-requirements) and `tail /var/logs/[httpd | apache2]/foobar_error.log` will be your friends here.